# Server & API load testing

Tags: testing, load-testing

I have custom API included in a website which creates new UID on new unique user visit like Google Analytics and sends the UID data to the backend server(NodeJs) for computation.

1. I need to check concurrent users and max the limit of users can be created/handled per current cloud config.
2. Also, need to check, is there any limit on API creating and sending users data. The API is on CDN(fastly)

Please suggest some testing tools, to check for above scenario.

Comment: Apache JMeter is recommended to test the API. http://jmeter.apache.org. Let me know if Apache JMeter satisfies your needs. I will put this in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I was looking for something where I can create virtual users, so I landed up with LoadRunner but it's paid do you know open source tools? which provide same.

Comment: JMeter serves your purpose :)

Answer (score 3):

- [SoapUI](http://soapui.org/) is a kind of standard for web services functional testing, it has also certain [load testing capabilities](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/concept.html)
- Web Services are basically JSON or SOAP over HTTP so **any** tool which supports HTTP protocol will suit. [Here](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview) you can find the list of free and open source load testing tools. Narrowed down to the most powerful ones it will look like:

  - [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
  - [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
  - [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
  - [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)

Check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article for the main features comparison, sample scripts and reports.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dmitry that those four (Grinder/Gatling/Tsung/Jmeter) are good tools, with a lot of functionality, but they are also fairly complex, require dependencies and can be somewhat painful to get started with. It all depends on your requirements which tool is best for you.

It sounds to me like you want to test one or two REST API end points powered by NodeJS. If you want a simple-to-get-started with tool that can be scripted, there are some good command-line tools available:

- [Wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) - very fast, scriptable in Lua
- [Artillery](https://artillery.io/) - NodeJS-based, scriptable in JS
- [k6](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6) - our own newly released tool, currently the fastest tool scriptable in JS

There is also [Locust](http://locust.io) which is scriptable in Python, but very low-performing.

I like these tools because they offer simple command-line usage and can be scripted in a real language, as opposed to Jmeter and Tsung, where you'll have to resort to XML if you want to do something slightly out of the ordinary. Gatling is a bit better, offering a DSL based on Scala classes where you can do most things but it is still not "real" Scala. The Grinder is the only one of those other tools that offers true scripting (in Jython), but again, it is not a simple one-line command to get started.